# Why can't I use operator< on 'std::deque'?

Tags: c++, deque, inequality

Ran cppcheck on my code base and received the following error:

```
Dangerous iterator comparison using operator< on 'std::deque'.
```

But a deque's iterator is a random access iterator, and random access iterators support inequality operators. So what gives?

Example:

```
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<int> d;
    std::deque<int>::iterator di1 = d.begin();
    std::deque<int>::iterator di2 = d.end();

    if (di1 < di2)
    {
        // (error) Dangerous iterator comparison using operator< on 'std::deque'.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: This bug was submitted and fixed via [cppcheck ticket #5926](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/5926).

Comment: Make sure you're comparing two iterators from the same container. I don't know how far into it cppcheck goes, so it might just always complain due to that possibility.

Comment: Please show the line that triggers this error.

Comment: We need to see the example code in order to help answer the question

Comment: Updated with example code.

Comment: Have you checked that this exact example code triggers the error? (Apologies if you have, but cppcheck can be finicky about context.)

Comment: Yes, it does trigger this error. (Totally understandable.)

Comment: @EvanRose, compiles perfectly fine on g++ and clang

Comment: That is crazypants, then. Yeah, there's absolutely nothing unsafe I can see about that code. cppcheck probably just isn't great at tracing what containers iterators belong to, outside the context of a for-loop.

Comment: Although the iterator comparison works, it might just be a lot slower than you expect. Maybe that's what the warning is trying to tell you.

Comment: I think it's a bug. Or at least something is amuck. I'm submitting a bug report because it doesn't complain about <= or >= operators, just < and >.

Comment: @MarkRansom, it is reporting it as an error though, which is surely incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug in cppcheck.

If we look at the code for the [rule `stlBoundaries()`](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/076f7a75420328e39203296b5191d005c39ac56f/lib/checkstl.cpp#L702), the containers it triggers on are:

```
"bitset|deque|list|forward_list|map|multimap|multiset|priority_queue|queue|set|stack|hash_map|hash_multimap|hash_set|unordered_map|unordered_multimap|unordered_set|unordered_multiset"
```

However, in addition to `deque`, `priority_queue` is also guaranteed to have random access iterators.

The rationale for this rule is that programmers might accidentally write:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); it < container.end(); ++it)
    ...
```

by analogy with the equivalent integer-indexed `for` loop, and this might actually compile for non-random-access iterators with some sort of conversion to pointer.

This is the original trac item that added the rule: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/247 and this ticket exempted `vector`: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/313

Comment: Note: there is no iterator on a `priority_queue` (this is a container adapter).